# Show image based on [row,column] array of BLOB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to do some image analysis in Matlab. What I have is an image which I first convert into an binary image using a threshold and then I use `bwlabel` to get the BLOBs of the image. I then find the indexes of the first BLOB and tries to show only the RGB values of this BLOB `I(row,column,:)`. However this obviously does not work and I don't know how to index the original image and get the corresponding RGB values based on the row, column data in the binary image. I suppose I could use a for-loop but the image is 4032 x 3024 and I want to do this kind of processing on a lot of images.

```
I = imread('someimg.jpg');
Ired   = I(:,:,1);
Igreen = I(:,:,2);
Iblue  = I(:,:,3);
% threshold
IBinary = Ired > 200 & Igreen > 150 & Iblue > 50;
IBinary = imopen(ISigns,strel('square',9));
% get labbelled BLOBs
IBinaryLabelled = bwlabel(IBinary,8);
% find index of the first label image
[row,column] = find(IBinaryLabelled == 1);
% Get RGB of the BLOB with label 1
RGB = I(row,column,:)
```

My question is therefore: How to get RGB values based on row,column data of binary image in an efficient manner?